# When I change the text for the button in SWT, the whole button size changes. How can I disable this?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, windowbuilder

I'm creating a piano program. But when I change the button text to nothing, the size of the button changes. How do I disable automatic resizing? I'm very new to windowbuilder. I've been googling for a while and can't find anything similar to my question.

```
package com.gmail.gogobebe2.piano;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class Piano extends Composite {

    /**
     * Create the composite.
     * @param parent
     * @param style
     */
    public Piano(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(9, false));
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(this, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        GridData gd_btnNewButton = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_btnNewButton.heightHint = 261;
        btnNewButton.setLayoutData(gd_btnNewButton);

        Button button_1 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));

        Button button = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button.setText("New Button");

        Button button_2 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button_2.setText("New Button");

        Button button_3 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button_3.setText("New Button");

        Button button_4 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_4.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button_4.setText("New Button");

        Button button_5 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_5.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button_5.setText("New Button");

        Button button_6 = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        button_6.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
        button_6.setText("New Button");

    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }

}
```

Here are some screenshots of before changed the button text and after I changed the button text

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After - changed 2 buttons text to be nothing**
[image: After]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the width of the buttons you can set the `widthHint` property of the `GridData`.
In your example, for the first button you can put: `gd_btnNewButton.widthHint = 100;`

For the other buttons you can change the lines of type:

```
button_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1));
```

with:

```
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
gd.widthHint = 100;
button_1.setLayoutData(gd);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've finished my Piano! :)